# Getting BitmapData in C# on Win 10 IoT core

Tags: c#, bitmap, bmp

For a project, I have to edit a Bitmap image using the Bitmap.lockBits() method in C#, which is no problem on a laptop, but on a Raspberry Pi 3 running the Windows 10 IoT Core, this generates an error saying:
"'MarshalByRefObj' claims to be specified in mscorlib, but can't be found."
This error is encountered on several other functions as well, but we can't work our way around it here.

After some research, I managed to figured out that means the method doesn't exist in the specified library. Trying to reference another mscorlib.dll is not an option, since VisualStudio automatically references the one on the machine itself.

So I need to know whether or not it's possible to use the Bitmap.lockBits() method, or to use another way to gain its advantages.

For testing purposes we are trying to get the MSDN Example code to work:

```
    private void LockUnlockBitsExample(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create a new bitmap.
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\fakePhoto.jpg");

        // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
            bmp.LockBits(rect,  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bmp.PixelFormat);
        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
        int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

        // Set every third value to 255. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.  
        for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
            rgbValues[counter] = 255;

        // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

        // Unlock the bits.
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        // Draw the modified image.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 150);

    }
```